# Missing template error on create action when trying to use factory girl to test user logins in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara, factory-bot, minitest

When I try to use a factory to test my login on my rails app, I keep getting a missing template error. It's expecting a template for my create action, even though I have a redirect in my controller. Here's my sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = login(params[:email], params[:password], params[:remember_me])
    if user
      redirect_back_or_to dashboard_path, :success => "Logged in!"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Email or password was invalid."
    end
  end

  def destroy
    logout
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged out!"
  end
end
```

And my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'pg'
gem 'heroku'
gem 'taps'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sorcery'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'capybara_minitest_spec'
  gem 'turn'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

My factories.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "foo#{n}@example.com" }
    password "secret"
    password_confirmation "secret"
  end
end
```

And here's my test:

require "test_helper"

```
describe "Login integration" do
  it "logs in a user successfully" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    visit login_path
    fill_in "Email", :with => user.email
    fill_in "Password", :with => user.password
    check "Remember me"
    click_button "Log in"
    current_path == "/dashboard"
    page.text.must_include "Logged in!"
    page.text.must_include "Your Dashboard"
  end

end
```

But I get this error when I run that test:

```
 Missing template sessions/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}.
```

Instead, if I just don't try to use factory girl, it works fine like this:

require "test_helper"

```
describe "Login integration" do
  it "logs in a user successfully" do
    visit signup_path
    fill_in "Email", :with => "joey@ramones.com"
    fill_in "Password", :with => "rockawaybeach"
    fill_in "Password confirmation", :with => "rockawaybeach"
    click_button "Create User"
    current_path == "/"
    page.text.must_include "Signed up!"
    visit login_path
    fill_in "Email", :with => "joey@ramones.com"
    fill_in "Password", :with => "rockawaybeach"
    check "Remember me"
    click_button "Log in"
    current_path == "/dashboard"
    page.text.must_include "Logged in!"
    page.text.must_include "Your Dashboard"
  end

end
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems clear that what's happening when you use `FactoryGirl` is that your `if` condition in the controller is evaluating to false (perhaps `login` is returning `nil`?). Since your redirect is only inside the conditional block, if you miss that then you'll fall through to the default render. So I don't know what your `login` method does, and thus can't tell you why `user` is `false` or `nil`, but it looks to me like that's got to be what's happening. Try adding a `redirect` or `render` for an existing view template in the `else` clause of your conditional and see if that prevents the exception.

Comment: This worked, when I added this `else
      redirect_to login_path, :alert => "Email or password was invalid."`
    end to my controller it fixed the problem.